# Calling protected properties without using $this->

Tags: php, oop, properties

I am reading a book about creating a MVC Framework in PHP. In the second chapter, we build a class that is a bit strange. Let me explain with an example.

The class is called `Inspector`. Here are the properties :

```
protected $_class;
protected $_properties = array();
protected $_methods = array();

protected $_meta = array(
            "class" => array(),
            "properties" => array(),
            "methods" => array()
    );
```

So as you can see, they are all declared protected.

But now, here is one of the many methods of the class :

```
public function getClassMethods()
{
    if (!isset($_methods))
    {
        $methods = $this->_getClassMethods();
        foreach ($methods as $method)
        {
            $_methods[] = $method->getName();
        }
    }
    return $_properties;
}
```

`_getClassMethods()` is a method that was declared a few lines above, but it is not important for our example.

So apparently, `$_methods` is the property declared previously. But why is it that it is not preceded by `$this->` ? First, I thought it is because the property is declared as `protected`, but I did some tests to see if it was normal and working, but of course it threw an error.

I can't believe the error comes from the book : the writers are professional PHP developers, I think, and they did the same mistake (?) in pretty much all of the other methods declared in the class.

So, is it possible for PHP to call a property without using `$this->` ? Does it have to do with a configuration line in php.ini (or something like that) ? Maybe it is because it's an old version of PHP that is used.

Comment: Check the book's web site to see if they have errata. I'm pretty sure there's no way to access a property without using `$this`. It's a common mistake for people coming from C++.

Comment: Prepending property and method names with underscores is one convention to differentiate private properties/methods from public ones (which then is without the underscore). It would be interesting to know which book this is

Comment: Are you sure you copied the function correctly? I wonder why the function would be named `getClassMethods()`, but it returns `$_properties` instead of `$_methods`.

Comment: The book got mostly negative reviews, although none of them mentioned that the code is so buggy. The Apress site has an address where you can submit errata, if you feel inspired.

Comment: You're probably right about the book (that it's a bit bad). It's quite frustrating because it seemed really good to understand MVC and build a MVC Framework :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your function, `$_methods` and `$this->_methods` would be two different variables/properties.

To access the `protected $_methods` property you need to use `$this->_methods`.  This is available in any method of the class.

If you just use `$_methods`, then you are creating/accessing a variable that will only exist inside that method and will go away when the method is finished executing.

Therefore, the book is incorrect and in your method you *need* to use `$this->_methods` and `$this->_properties`.

Comment: So how can `if(isset($_methods))` ever be true, since it's a local variable that has never been set? And then what's the point of assigning to it in the loop if it will just go away?

Comment: And what does `return $_properties` return, since it's also a local variable but it's never set in the function?

Comment: @Barmar: Let me try to reword my answer.  I was just trying to explain the difference between using `$this->` and not using it.  That `isset` will *always* be `false`, because you need to use `$this->` in this case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But then, why is there a `if` statement to check if the variable doesn't exist (we no the variable doesn't exist in the function). Also, why does the name of the variable starts with the underscore (_) character, I thought this character was used to declare protected/private properties and methods  ?

Comment: It seems like the OP already understood the difference. But as the function is written, it seems like it should only be sensible if you could access properties as if they're normal variables, and that's what his question is about.

Comment: @tomfl: The `if` statement if checking *both* whether it exists and whether it's set (to a value).  Also, starting variables with an `_` is usually used for private/protected variables, it's just a style choice.

Comment: But it obviously doesn't exist, since it has never been used previously in the function. It's like doing `$var = 1; if ($var == 1) ...`?

Comment: Ah, yes... looks like I just misunderstood what was being said.  This is just a typo in the book, there is no way to access those class properties without `$this->`.

Comment: @Barmar : you are right. I just started reading this book, and I came across a lot of strange things like this. The big question is : is it a mistake from the authors (in that case, it's a very very big mistake because they have been repeating it for 200 lines), or am I just missing something ?

Comment: As JimL asked above, what book is it? If they have lots of code like this, it seems like they just don't know PHP well and didn't hire a good reviewer.

Comment: @tomfl: This has got to be a mistake in the book, I don't know of anyway to access class methods without `$this->`.  I hope my answer is better now, I didn't understand the question at first, sorry :)

Comment: RocketHazmat : no it's okay, thanks :) 
@Barmar : The book is Pro PHP MVC, edited by Apress. You can probably look inside on Amazon, it's page 23 or 24 (you can't miss it).